# How to design a road with a certain slope

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, road

Is there a way that you want to connect two different points of altitude with a constant slope of 7%  or another, to draw a line in the 3D model?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Yes, it is possible - there is even an infinite number of such lines. Could you tell a bit more on the purpose of doing that? Are there some constraints on the length and shape of the line? Do you use a specific software?

Comment: I use QGIS, arcGIS ..
I have a point A and point B different altitude. It is necessary to merge them with a 7% incline for example to draw that line automatically.

Comment: Do you have a Spatial Analyst license?  AFAIK, the only code in ArcGIS that can solve this problem is [PathDistance](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Path_Distance/009z0000001q000000/)

Comment: I have a licence for this tool, but I do not need distance between points, I need client software to draw a curve with a constant slope between points.
When I make overlay with a map to see how it looks, that way.
Which tool is needed to do to?

Comment: PathDistance computes routes that meet requirements based on location and direction. Set it up so that any route steeper than 7% has a huge cost and anything 7% or less has (almost) no cost.  PathDistance *should* find short routes meeting these criteria. As @julien notes, though, there usually are still infinitely many solutions.  (Note that if you try to make the slope a *constant* 7% then in many cases there will be *no* solutions.)

Answer (score 1):

As @whuber says in his comments you should be able to use **[PathDistance](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Path_Distance/009z0000001q000000/)** to do this.

"PathDistance computes routes that meet requirements based on location and direction. Set it up so that any route steeper than 7% has a huge cost and anything 7% or less has (almost) no cost. PathDistance should find short routes meeting these criteria. As @julien notes, though, there usually are still infinitely many solutions. (Note that if you try to make the slope a constant 7% then in many cases there will be no solutions.)"